# Не работают эмуляторы в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, avd

Установила `Android Studio`, создаю эмулятор (AVD). После запуска эмулятора отображается просто мобильный с черным экраном. Через некоторое время выдает ошибку:

> Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online

Comment: Последние версии глючные ещё больше, чем обычно. В интернете есть разные решения этой проблемы, поможет или нет - неизвестно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Сперва Попробуй очистить память у устройства
2. Проверь работает ли у тебя Intel Haxm.
3. Проверь хватает ли у тебя памяти чтобы запускать эмулятор, если не хватает то лезь в настройки
4. Почитай документацию и рекомендации в офф сайте developer.android
5. Попробуй универсальный adb драйвер установить, переустановить
6. Проверь и обнови все sdк в slk менеджере
   Это довольно распространенная проблема и можешь почитать в интернете, если найдешь скажи как пофиксил, а если нет то apk.файл находится в app - build - outputs - apk - debug.